# MYSQL one to many relation on one query?

Tags: mysql, one-to-many

I'm trying to get (for example) the post's comments.
I have two tables, post and comment. The comment table have a Foreign Key to the post that belong.

is it possible make one query to get an array like this?

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [title] => post title
            [content] => post content
            [comment] =>
                [0] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [id] => 105
                        [content] => This is a comment
                    )
                [1] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [id] => 199
                        [content] => This is other comment
                    )               
        )
)
```

obviously, if the result is an array of array or array of objects, doesn't matter

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4326561/mysql-struggling-with-query-in-one-to-many-relationship-matching-multiple-condit

Comment: No, it's not the same topic! Thanks